# How did Krieg contact the Imperium after their civil war?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The civil war on Krieg lasted for 5 centuries:

> From the self-annihilation of their homeworld, loyalist troops slowly retook their world inch by inch over the course of 500 years until finally returning to Imperial rule in 949.M40.
>
> From the [Lexicanum Article on Krieg](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Krieg)

The only way of faster-than-light communication in Warhammer 40k are Astropaths. Even though the Imperium has live-prolonging technology, I doubt that it was available on Krieg during their civil war as the planet was sealed off of the Imperium and the resources on Krieg were used for the war. So I assume, there wasn't an Astropath around for communication?! Then, how exactly did Krieg notify the wider Imperium that their civial war was over after 500 years and that they'd like to join again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Planet Likely Was Never Out of Contact**
You may be misunderstanding the phrase "returning to Imperial rule in 949.M40."  That doesn't indicate that they were totally out of contact with the Imperium for 500 years, it means that the planet was not totally under loyalist control until 949.M40.

Indeed, Krieg's previous designation as a Hive World probably means it was never "out of contact" with imperial authorities for any significant length of time.  Even if the loyalist astropaths on Ferrograd (the last loyalist hive pre-nuclear holocaust) were all killed, the nature of Imperial supply means that ships would have been constantly arriving in-system.  Hive Worlds import huge amounts of foodstuffs and export whatever products they specialize in.  It's a near-continuous cycle of import and export.  Even if by some miracle or cunning ploy by the traitors supply ships were absent at the start of the war, they'd still arrive at some point.  So the Imperium would know about the civil war. Now what?

Then per Siege of Vraks Book I, the Imperium didn't have the troops or ships on-hand to fight against the Krieg rebels, which led to the Loyalist holdout on Ferrograd nuking the planet.  That doesn't mean the Imperium had 0 ships in orbit.  For the first bit of the war they probably had rogue traders and transports coming in who left before word of the war reached them.  Then navy vessels passing through (Hive Worlds tend to be sub-sector hubs and Krieg was no exception) would use sub-light transmissions at the very least to monitor the situation for the next 500 years of war.  There's no record of Krieg Traitors controlling the orbitals above the whole planet, so the Ferrograd loyalists may even have gotten occasional supply from the wider imperium during the war.

That's not to say they were talking to the wider Imperium every day, but in the scope of "Planet in contact with the Imperium" even a once-every-10-years communication back and forth or ship arriving is pretty good, and I would bet based on Krieg's location and former importance it was way more often than that.

**TL/DR**
Krieg was almost certainly in near-continuous (from an Imperial perspective) contact with the wider Imperium during all 500 years of war.  The phrase "returning to Imperial rule in 949.M40" indicates complete loyalist control of the planet, not the planet's reintroduction to the wider imperium after 500 years.

Comment: You have a similar style to someone that has posted a few answers recently through unregistered accounts. If you're wanting to participate a lot and stick around you might consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161) and if the other accounts belong to you also [merging them together](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).